# Mocking urllib3.PoolManager().request function with python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, urllib3

I have a function that makes a POST request using urllib3.PoolManager(). Now in the unit test I want to mock said request but having some difficulty. What's the correct way to do it?

My code:

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
# my func
def func(event, context):
    ...
    resp = http.request('POST', url, body=encoded_msg)
    ...

# unit test
@patch('urllib3.PoolManager.request')
def test_lambda_handler(self, mock_instance):
    mock_instance.return_value = Mock(status = "200", data = "success")
    res = func(event, [])
    mock_instance.request.assert_called_once()
```

I get this error "AssertionError: Expected 'request' to have been called once. Called 0 times."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you call the constructor of the `urllib3.PoolManager` class in **global (or module) scope**. Reference: [#where-to-patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

> module `b` does `import a` and `some_function` uses `a.SomeClass`. ... In this case the class we want to patch is being looked up in the module and so we have to patch `a.SomeClass` instead: `@patch('a.SomeClass')`

**Option 1: import the `func` after mocking `urllib3.PoolManager` class**

`lambda_handler.py`:

```py
import urllib3
import json

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
print('http: ', http)

def func(event, context):
    url = 'http://localhost:3000'
    data = {'attribute': 'value'}
    encoded_msg = json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8')
    resp = http.request('POST', url, body=encoded_msg)
```

`test_lambda_handler.py`:

```py
import unittest
import json
from unittest import mock


class TestLambdaHandler(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('urllib3.PoolManager')
    def test_lambda_handler(self, mock_PoolManager):
        from lambda_handler import func
        mock_http = mock_PoolManager.return_value
        event = {}
        func(event, [])
        mock_http.request.assert_called_once_with('POST', 'http://localhost:3000', body=json.dumps({'attribute': 'value'}).encode('utf-8'))


unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

test result:

```
test_lambda_handler (__main__.TestLambdaHandler) ... http:  <MagicMock name='PoolManager()' id='4475122928'>
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.063s

OK
Name                                                Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/69890084/lambda_handler.py            9      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/69890084/test_lambda_handler.py      12      0   100%
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                  21      0   100%
```

**Option 2: mock the global variable `http`, you don't need to import the `func` after mocking**

If you import the `lambda_handler` module at the top of the test file, the module `lambda_handler` will have a reference to the real `urllib3.PoolManager` so that it's too late for mocking.

```py
import unittest
import json
from unittest import mock
from lambda_handler import func


class TestLambdaHandler(unittest.TestCase):
    @mock.patch('lambda_handler.http')
    def test_lambda_handler(self, mock_http):
        event = {}
        func(event, [])
        mock_http.request.assert_called_once_with('POST', 'http://localhost:3000', body=json.dumps({'attribute': 'value'}).encode('utf-8'))


unittest.main(verbosity=2)
```

test result:

```
http:  <urllib3.poolmanager.PoolManager object at 0x1104b2610>
test_lambda_handler (__main__.TestLambdaHandler) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
Name                                                Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/69890084/lambda_handler.py            9      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/69890084/test_lambda_handler.py      11      0   100%
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                                  20      0   100%
```